# Why all these variants on correct formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro that combines three reports in to one.
I first find the dynamic name by looking at open workbooks to find a matching name

```
For Each wk In Workbooks
    If Left(wk.Name, 14) = "PayrollSummary" Then
        Set wbpay = Workbooks(wk.Name)
    End If
    If Left(wk.Name, 12) = "PunchedHours" Then
        Set wbpun = Workbooks(wk.Name)
    End If
Next
```

And from the start this line worked (ws is the report it's working on).

```
ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,['" & wbpay.Name & "']payrollsummary!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"
```

Then that line started acting up and this worked:

```
ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,[" & wbpay.Name & "]payrollsummary!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"
```

Now I have added a third:

```
On Error Resume Next
ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,['" & wbpay.Name & "']payrollsummary!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"
ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,[" & wbpay.Name & "]payrollsummary!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"
ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'[" & wbpay.Name & "]payrollsummary'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"
On Error GoTo 0
```

Because today only the third line worked.
Here is an example of the formula in the Excel:

[image]

The workbook name will always be `ParollSummary_DateFrom_DateTo_SomeRandomStuff.xlsx`.
Looking at the image it seems I have accidentally downloaded the file twice (1).
But either way, I still don't see the reason why three different lines of code works randomly (my impression) with different files.
Is there any way to make sure it will always work so that I don't need to find out what will be the correct way next week?

Comment: delete "On Error Resume Next" and try to run.

Comment: In that case it will error on first two lines, and the third will work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Zv2.png

Comment: "acting up" is not a very useful description of what problem you're seeing.

Comment: That the formula does not work. I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Zv2.png

Comment: The last one looks correct.   https://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/referencing_cells_outside_the_worksheet.html

Comment: @Techie `?wbpay.name
 PayrollSummary_20210201_20210207_8ccd52a0426023805d (1).xlsx`

Comment: @TimWilliams OK.. The other two variants has been taken from manually creating the formula and "making them VBA". Why would Excel create a formula that is "not correct in all circumstances"

Comment: When you created the code there was no space in the workbook name?

Comment: Probably.. Since space only comes from windows renaming to not overwrite an old copy. Still quite annoying that Excel does not create the formula that always works.

Comment: It is mandatory to place the name/path between `'` characters only if **there are spaces in their name**. The variant containing " (1)" has a space...

Comment: Excel doesn't create the formula, you are. The exact process is that you are instructing VBA to concoct a string that, when assigned to the `Formula` property, will be interpreted by Excel as a formula.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for posting an "Answer" here but the discussion is running out of space. Let's look at your code in detail.

```
For Each wk In Workbooks
    If Left(wk.Name, 14) = "PayrollSummary" Then
        Set wbpay = Workbooks(wk.Name)
    End If
    If Left(wk.Name, 12) = "PunchedHours" Then
        Set wbpun = Workbooks(wk.Name)
    End If
Next
```

It's not clear why a workbook name that starts with "PayrollSummary" should be checked whether it also starts with "PunchedHours". The two are mutually exclusive. When both are found the search should stop and when one of them isn't found the rest of your macro shouldn't be executed. Either of these things could happen with your above code leading to the errors that follow later. The code below wouldn't have the faults just described.

```
Sub Trial()

    Dim WbPay       As Workbook
    Dim WbPun       As Workbook
    
    If GetWorkbook(WbPay, "PayrollSummary") Then
        If Not GetWorkbook(WbPun, "PunchedHours") Then Exit Sub
        
        ' continue your code here
        Debug.Print WbPay.Name
        Debug.Print WbPun.Name
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetWorkbook(Wb As Workbook, _
                             WbName As String) As Boolean

    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, Wb.Name, WbName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
        GetWorkbook = True
        Exit For
    Next Wb
End Function
```

Now we know that the rest of the code can't fail because one of the workbooks wasn't found. Both *WbPay* and *WbPun* actually exist and are open.

That leads to the question why we need to use a worksheet function to access them. Since all their content is accessible, why not just get it? But you want this:-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,['ParollSummary_DateFrom_DateTo_SomeRandomStuff.xlsx']payrollsummary!$B:$B,1,FALSE),"Fel")
```

There are three questions attached to this demand.

1. In which workbook is the formula? Bear in mind that `A5` is on the ActiveSheet of that workbook. What will happen if the sheet on which the formula is entered isn't active at that time? I don't know but if Excel would attempt to execute the formula in such a scenario an error must occur - probably an error 1004.
2. 'ParollSummary_DateFrom_DateTo_SomeRandomStuff.xlsx' should be `WbPay.Name`. Why not use that definition? It would guarantee that the referenced workbook really exists and is open. We don't know that of 'ParollSummary_DateFrom_DateTo_SomeRandomStuff.xlsx'. In fact, the name contains a spelling error even here (lifted from your published code).
3. Why do you wish to return a value from columns(1) of the look-up array? That would be the same value as you have in A5. Not that this would cause an error in itself but it adds to the general confusion.

The verdict, therefore, is that your plan is high in risk and low in precision. The solution must be in reducing the risk and increasing the precision.

Comment: First off, I have no problems with running for each code. It's only me that uses this code and I know I need three reports open before I run it. Sure I could exit the loop after finding the two, but I generally only have these three or possibly one more open. The formula is written to a workbook called `Dagmar Dagab Frukt & Grönt version 2.0 (12).xlsx`. This time it was 12, next time it's 13 probably... It's a dynaic naming here also. The code runs from a add-in, the start of code first makes sure this workbook is active before doing anything else. Your "2": that is what I do. Look at the VBA

Comment: code. `ws.Range("K5").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A5,'[" & wbpay.Name & "]payrollsummary'!$B:$B,1,FALSE),""Fel"")"` where wbpay is refering to the workbook with the variable name that was found a few lines above. And ws here is the `Dagmar.... (12)` file. (3) Because that way I can know if the value of this row is linked in wbpay or wbpun. If Vlookup fails in wbpay then the value has to exist in wbpun.

Comment: Apologies! Apparently I was looking at my working copies of your code instead of the original when assessing your problem. My approach is driven by inherent distrust of using VBA to write worksheet functions. The function you try to write is a complicated one and your experience fortifies my distrust. I would look for a solution that doesn't involve writing a formula which Excel has difficulty accepting under the given circumstances.